# long running application (tail like)

Tags: java, tail, long-running-processes

I want to write an tail like app. Now this app, scans a file for changes in the background and fires events in case something changed.

I want to run my application until the user requests to exit it by pressing ctrl + c (working by default). I do not want to create a lot of CPU load just by doing an endless `while(true)` loop like I'm doing ATM:

```
try {
        // thread doing the monitoring
        thread.start();

        // forcing the programm not to exit
        while (System.in.available() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does anyone know a more elegant/the right approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a thread in the first place, the 'tail' unix script is simply a `while(true)` loop with no exit condition. It watches the file and prints changes if any is detected. I think by default it pauses 1 second, so basically:

```
while(true) {
   // Code goes here. Watch file, System.out.print if it changes

   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

No need for a thread. But to answer the question about the best way to keep your app alive: Simply don't return from the thread's `run()` method. You don't have to join the thread, the application will stay in the foreground as long as it has one non-daemon running thread.

Comment: I thought a while(true) look will cause a lot of unnessesary load to my cpu.

Comment: That's what the sleep is for.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I always thougt there is a "better" way :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the System.in without busy-waiting, that's very easy to achieve. `InputStream` has **blocking** semantics so all you need to to is call one of the `read` methods and it will block until there is input available. If you are scanning text input, I'd advise `BufferedReader.readLine`. Also, do that on the main thread, no point in starting another one.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it's more clear now. Why did somebody of you downvote my post?

Comment: What do you mean by "somebody of you?" Do you take me personally for a keeper of the entire SO?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was you, because you said its unclear what I want. I'm sorry about this imputation!

Comment: You should refrain from doing that on SO. If you want to contend a downvote, comment under your question with @downvoter tag. It's not going to notify the downvoter, but at least you're not going to be throwing accusations at people who are actually helping you. There, I upvoted your Q so you don't feel sore about it :)

Comment: Thanks, now I now. Next time I will do better!